# ArrayFormula Only Iterating The First Value Throughout the Column, Need All the Values that Fit the Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

The problem:

I have two sheets,
**Auto Expenses & Business Expenses** (duplicate sheets with different categories of expenses)
Column J represents the cost of an expenses
Column F represents the date of the expense

I am trying to **create a function that will add up all of the expenses between both sheets given a start date & an end date and iterate down the column**

Here is the function I wrote:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(F2:F),"",SUMIFS('Auto Expenses'!$J$7:$J,'Auto Expenses'!$F$7:$F,">="&O2:O,'Auto Expenses'!$F$7:$F,"<="&P2:P)+SUMIFS('Business Expenses'!$J$7:$J,'Business Expenses'!$F$7:$F,">="&O2:O,'Business Expenses'!$F$7:$F, "<="&P2:P)))
```

**O2:O** is a **list of start dates** & **P2:P** is a **list of end dates**>

When I run the function, it will only return the first sum of the expenses and iterate all the way down with the same value.

**What am I doing wrong?**

If I use this function instead and drag is down, it gives the proper results, but I want it to iterate down the column automatically

```
=SUMIFS('Auto Expenses'!$J$7:$J,'Auto Expenses'!$F$7:$F,">="&O2,'Auto Expenses'!$F$7:$F, "<="&P2)+SUMIFS('Business Expenses'!$J$7:$J,'Business Expenses'!$F$7:$F,">="&O2,'Business Expenses'!$F$7:$F, "<="&P2)
```

Here is a link to a copy of the spreadsheet for reference: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lbrvsrz90RSYhedwA8IkyoYlHqWy5Lw7Ngxw5eRjAKs/edit?usp=sharing[enter](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lbrvsrz90RSYhedwA8IkyoYlHqWy5Lw7Ngxw5eRjAKs/edit?usp=sharing%5Benter) image description here][1]

Comment: `SUMIFS` is not supported by `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Comment: Unable to access sheet via link - plz make it shareable

Comment: @TomSharpe I have granted access to the spreadsheet now. You should be able to view & edit

Comment: @idfurw oh I forgot about sumifs not being supported by arrayformula. So then would I have to do a sumif for each condition and just add them all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your time intervals are all seven days, one approach is to develop a 2d array with 7 columns where each column represents a different day of the week, and use that in a sumif to get the totals for each day. Then use Mmult to sum across the 7 days:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(O2:O="",,mmult(sumif('Auto Expenses'!F7:F,O2:O+sequence(1,7,0),'Auto Expenses'!J7:J),sequence(7,1,1,0))))
```

[image]

Then do the same thing for business expenses (which isn't yet populated in your sample sheet).

Comment: Wow I didn't even know =SEQUENCE was a function I could use! I'm new to learning about Google Sheets/Excel arrays so this is very helpful to know. Thank you